# Linking nested documents together and facetting in ElasticSearch

Tags: search, lucene, elasticsearch

I have a mapping which looks like this:

```
"mappings": {
    "mydoc": {
        "properties": {
            "event": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                    "eventType": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "idList": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "id": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    },
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A mydoc document contains a nested array of event documents.

Within a mydoc document, I want to find all IDs where:

- There exists an event with event.type='A' and event.idList contains some ID X
- There exists another event with event.type='B' and event.id equals X

Across the index, I want a list of IDs where this criteria holds and also a count (for each ID) of the number of mydoc documents this occurred in.

Is it possible to achieve this in ElasticSearch? I was thinking it might be possible with a nested facet filter or a terms filter lookup but I have not seen a way to do it with these yet.

Answer (score 0):

I think that a parent-child relation might suit your case better then a nested document.
Then you can query you (child) events document directly if you're searching only in the scope of the events (or add a condition on the [_parent](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-parent-field.html) field to limit to a specific top document).
And you can use the has_child filter or query to search (or facet) on your top documents with conditions on the events (see http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-has-child-filter.html )

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I'm not sure how this would help - if event docs were children of mydoc docs, then I could use has_child to find all mydocs which have an event of type A (with a specific id X in the idlist) and an event of type B  (with X as the id)  but I would have to specify the value for X. What I actually want to do is find all ids where this condition holds (I don't want to have to specify an id)... is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. Do you want to get all the ids where event = A or B? If so you can do a boolean search with the conditions on the event type and idList with a facet on the id field, this will give you the list of ids.

Comment: No.. I want to search within top level docs (mydoc documents) and find where the nested array of events contains at least two events where one is type A and another is type B, and these two events share an ID (where the ID appears in the idList field of A and the id field of B). I want to find all IDs where this is true within a single mydoc document, and later I want to search across all mydoc documents and aggregate the IDs with counts

Comment: (IDs are not unique per event, they are just numbers that appear in the idList field of type A events and the id field of type B events)

Comment: You mean you don't know the ID you're looking for but your condition is that both events A and B share an ID? Ah, I don't think you can achieve that easily. It's possible you can do that using a script (and in that case parent-child is not what you need), but it may have nasty performance, depending on your data size.